# How to run a VBScript that is located in a jar?

Tags: java, vbscript, jar

Is it possible to execute a vbs that is located inside a jar or is there a way arround it? 
I am using vbs for basic wmi tasks.
I could not find something similar.

Comment: http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/.

Comment: You'd need to extract the VBScript from the jar file to be able to run it.

Comment: Thank you. I came across this earlier... this would do a part of the job. But in my case it is necessary that the vbs is executed. I should have said that. sry @AnsgarWiechers ok thanks for the hint

Comment: If you can use COM, you can create an instance of the MSScriptControl (32 bit programs only - 64 bit has to use confusing Windows Script Interface), load your script and execute it.